# How to show statistics like qps of all databases on a mysql server

Tags: mysql, linux

Maybe someone here knows the answer to my question: How do I show statistics like qps and similar of all databases on my mysql server to determine which ones use the most qps.

Already thanks for the answers! :)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12703/76803

Comment: will have a look thank you